# How to hide the Intercom chat widget in specific pages in a single page application (SPA)?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, intercom

Consider a single page application written in vanilla JS (to avoid framework-specific answers).

I have an app in which I load Intercom by default, but I want to hide the widget in specific pages.

That should be doable from Intercom itself, as shown in [this article](https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/189-turn-off-show-or-hide-the-intercom-messenger) in their help center, but it doesn't really work in single page apps - the widget is shown no matter what is configured in Intercom.

One option would be to find the widget on page and hide it manually for the given pages, but that feels, sounds and tastes like a hack (it requires re-enabling the widget when going back to page where the widget is supposed to appear).

So, is there any good practice on how to do it for SPAs?

Comment: You can conditionally add a CSS class to BODY when you enter the given pages and remove the class when exiting the given pages. Then you can target the Intercom widget with a CSS selector and make it `display: none`

Comment: @IVOGELOV that's pretty much what I said about what feels like a hack. Making it with CSS selectors instead of js doesn't make it any better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to hide the intercom launcher programmatically, you can do this with the `update` command.

To hide:

```
Intercom('update', {
  "hide_default_launcher": true
});
```

And to show it again (when your next page loads, or the event is triggered that should show it).

```
Intercom('update', {
  "hide_default_launcher": false
});
```

I used this exact technique in an angular SPA to hide it on screens where it was obscuring some buttons.

Comment: Tip: it is worth checking that `Intercom` exists on the window object before trying to access it (`"Intercom" in window`), because some users will have browser extensions that block the Intercom script from being downloaded. Doing this check will save you an error at runtime.

Comment: What would the full script be?

Comment: @OldGreg `if (window.Intercom) window.Intercom('upda...` or `if (typeof window.Intercom  !== 'undefined') ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
Intercom('update', {
     "hide_default_launcher": true
});
$(".helpSupport").once().on("click", function() {
     Intercom('update', {
        "hide_default_launcher": false
     });
      Intercom('showMessages');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code when you load your user data, and set your widget visibility default

```
// Intercom logged in user variables loader
(<any>window).Intercom("boot", {
    app_id: "abc",
    name: user.username,
    email: user.email,
    created_at: moment(user.addedDate).unix()
  });

// Hide messenger widget after loading user variables
// Will show it manually in specific pages
if ((<any>window).Intercom) (<any>window).Intercom("update", {
     "hide_default_launcher": true
});
```

Add this code in your guard or navigator to show/hide it in all pages as per your defaults

```
// Hide messenger widget for all pages by default
// Will show it manually in specific pages
if ((<any>window).Intercom) (<any>window).Intercom("update", {
     "hide_default_launcher": true
});
```

Then show/hide it in specific pages

```
ngOnInit()
{
    // Show messenger widget for current page
    // This code will override the default one in auth-guard/navigator
    if ((<any>window).Intercom) (<any>window).Intercom("update", {
     "hide_default_launcher": false
    });
}
```

Use this link if need to see all boot/update attributes
https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/javascript-api-attributes-objects

Answer (score 0):

I call this piece of code, when i call my component.

```
window.Intercom('update', {
    hide_default_launcher: false,
  });
```

Exemple:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
     window.Intercom('update', {
        hide_default_launcher: false,
      });

  return (
<div>...</div>);
};
```

The downside is that you have to set ***hide_default_launcher*** to ***true*** when you want the widget appear next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can include/exclude pages in your intercom settings based on the current page url, which works for our SPA. The instructions are in the [article](https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/189-turn-off-show-or-hide-the-intercom-messenger) you linked to in your question, under "Show the Messenger launcher to select website visitors".

- Go to messenger settings > control your inbound conversation volume
- Select 'visitors who match certain data'
- Select 'add data' and add the attribute 'current page URL' to define a page where you do/don't want to show the intercom launcher

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29843699)

Comment: This only works on page reloads of the SPA. Which, the whole point is to not reload the data. I'm assuming it doesn't pay attention to browser route events since it only matters based on what page is initially landed on.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to use this instruction

```
https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/189-turn-off-show-or-hide-the-intercom-messenger
```

And I used it until it worked.  And after some time intercom started ignoring the option 'hide_default_launcher'. So I disabled it by disabling its loading.

```
          await page.route('https://widget.intercom.io/**/*', async route => {
              await page.evaluate(() => {
                  if (window && (window as any).intercomSettings) {
                      // Disables the Intercom Chat by stating the "hide_default_launcher" as true
                      (window as any).intercomSettings.hide_default_launcher = true;
                      (window as any).Intercom = () => {
                          console.log('intercom function disabled');
                      };
                      (window as any).intercomInstance = () => {
                          console.log('intercom instance disabled');
                      };
                      console.log('disabling intercom instance');
                  }
              });
              await route.fulfill({
                  status: 200,
                  contentType: 'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8',
                  body: 'console.log("intercom source disabled")'
              });
          });
```